# Why can Cryosat's dual antenna "better discern steep slopes" of Antarctic ice than Sentinel-3?

Tags: earth-observation, esa, radar, sentinel-spacecraft

The BBC's [Climate change: Satellite fix safeguards Antarctic data](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-47461199) explains that earlier problems of missing data near the coasts have been addressed, and though scientists are hopeful, there is lingering concern:

> Sentinel-3's data still needs work where the terrain is steeply sloping - at the edges of Antarctica and along its peninsula - but in its first elevation map of the continent, the satellite is capturing the key areas of mass loss in the western ice sheet.
>
> "Around Pine Island and Thwaites, it's clearly picking out the main signals of dynamic imbalance. These are the hotspots of thinning. So, it's seeing the important stuff," said Dr McMillan.
>
> "The peninsula has always been difficult for radar altimeters, just because of the size of the radar footprint versus the size of the glaciers. But I think this is something that will evolve.
>
> "It's easy to forget the Sentinel-3 mission is new and it's likely that as more people work on its data with new approaches - it will be possible to extract more information."

The article then explains the superiority of the Cryosat radar altimeter for these areas especially:

> The question for the European Union and its technical partner, the European Space Agency, is whether they could do even better?
>
> The Cryosat spacecraft - as its name suggests - is a specialised ice-monitoring satellite. It was an experiment with dual-antenna technology that outperforms all other radar altimeters in those hard-to-sense mountainous locations.
>
> [...]
>
> "Ground processing can be upgraded after launch, but not the altimeter itself," commented Dr Amandine Guillot from the French space agency (Cnes)
>
> "That's why, for example, the Sentinel-3 altimeter is not able to retrieve as much data as Cryosat over the coastal zone of Antarctica.
>
> "That is why the Cristal mission, which has the primary objective of ice monitoring, has a real added-value with respect to the Sentinel-3 mission."

**THE QUESTION:** What is it exactly about Cryosat's "dual antenna interferometer that can better discern steep slopes" of Antarctic ice than Sentinel-3's radar?

> Artwork: Cryosat has a dual antenna interferometer that can better discern steep slopes. ESA

[image: Cryosat has a dual antenna interferometer, ESA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SIRAL instrument has better spatial resolution due to its waveform processing:

> Unlike conventional radar altimeters, where the interval between
>   pulses is about 500 us, the CryoSat-2 altimeter will send a burst of
>   pulses with an interval of only 50 us between them. The returning
>   echoes will be correlated, and by treating the whole burst at once,
>   the data processor can separate the echo into strips arranged across
>   the track by exploiting the slight frequency shifts (caused by the
>   Doppler effect) in the forward- and aft-looking parts of the beam.

(From https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-operational-eo-missions/cryosat/instruments/siral )

The two antennas are part of this modulation scheme.

> Each strip is about 250 m wide and the interval between bursts is
>   arranged so that the satellite moves forward by 250 m each time. The
>   strips laid down by successive bursts can therefore be superimposed on
>   each other and averaged to reduce noise. This mode of operation is
>   called the Synthetic Aperture Radar, or SAR mode. ￼
>
> Phase difference between returning radar waves In order to measure the
>   arrival angle, a second receive antenna is activated to receive the
>   radar echo with two antennas simultaneously. When the echo comes from
>   a point not directly beneath the satellite there will be a difference
>   in the path-length of the radar wave, which will be measured. Simple
>   geometry provides the angle between the baseline, joining the antennas, and the echo direction.

Effectively, SAR processing with the two antennas is used in place of a single larger antenna and imaging sensor.